# Finding a strongly connected component with a desired node in it

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, breadth-first-search

Given a directed graph, and one of the vertices `x`,  I need to find a strongly connected component in the graph that includes `x`.
The algorithm should be linear, and to use bfs only.

Comment: What has your research turned up as a possible approach to this problem? How did your approach fail to give you the correct answer?

Comment: I know how to find strongly connected components in a graph using SCC algorithm. But i find it difficult to understand how can i find one in the graph with the vertice x using bfs... I couldn't find any similar problems to mine

Comment: When I googled "strongly connected component bfs", the first link returned was very helpful.

Comment: well i think i figured it out somehow. i know that directed graph is strongly connected if there is a path from x to all vertices and back to x. and if it applies to the transposed graph as well. i just can't understand how to return a specific  strongly connected component that has x on it..

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how this got to the top of my page after all this time but it's missing an answer, so...

To find the strongly connected component that contains a given node **x**, you can do a BFS from **x** to find all the nodes reachable from **x**.  Then reverse all the edges and do a BFS from **x** to find all the nodes reachable through reverse edges.  Those are all the nodes in the original graph from which **x** can be reached.

The intersection of those sets of nodes is the SCC that contains **x**.